# Is it possible to share a dashboard with a role instead of user?

Tags: share, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles, dashboard

Is it possible to share a dashboard with a role instead of user?

Thanks,
Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible (as far as I know).

It's not sharing a dashboard but maybe transfering ownership with GRANT OWNERSHIP of the dashboard to a role helps you a little? (Goal: All users of the rule have ownership then)

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html

Comment: Thanks Marcel, we'll try to do so.